# Python: read file, store rows as list and create list of rows

Tags: python

I have a data file with a certain amount of rows and columns that I import. I want to store the values of each row in a list and finally create a list consisting of the lists of each row, e.g. a simplified version:

Input:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

And as outcome I want

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

My code atm:

```
result = []
col1 = []
for line in lines[1:]:

    # split the line into fields based on white space
    fields = line.split()

    # convert the text to numbers, make list of values in row k
    while k < real: 
        col = float(fields[k])
        col1.append(col)
        k+=1

    else:
        result.append(col1)  #make list of lists of values in rows
        k=0                 #Reset k for other loop using k
        del col1[:]        #Delete temp list

        print result
```

For some reason after del col1[:], result also gets emptied. Any idea why this is?

Any suggestions on how to do this in a more simplified way are always welcome! As you'll probably have noticed, I'm not that experienced with python.

Note that in my real case I have a data-file with 100 columns and 108k rows.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: May I ask why you need a list of every row? With 108k rows and 100 columns, that will eat a lot of memory. If you're going to just iterate over it later, I suggest keeping it as the csv and iterating over csv.reader() instead. It's a generator so you don't have every single piece of data taking up memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Answer(s)

Using Python 2.x it's as simple as

```
list_of_lists = [map(int,l.split()) for l in open('data.txt').readlines()]
```

but for Python 3.x the `map` builtin returns a generator, not a list so it has to be written using list comprehension (LC)

```
lol = [[int(s) for s in l.split()] for l in open('data.txt').readlines()]
```

BTW, the second possibility works as well in Python 2.x, so from a compatibility POV it could be the preferred approach.

### Why does it works?

Let's focus on the second answer, our list of lists (LOL) is built using a nested list comprehension, the outer producing a list of objects produced by the inner one, i.e., lists, hence a LOL as requested...

The fundamental concept is that you need not an explicit loop on the lines of a file because every file object, as returned from the `open` builtin, has a `.readlines` method that returns a list of lines, each line represented by a string terminated by the linefeed character.

The elements of this list (the lines) can be split in individual elements using the `.split` method of strings --- by default `split` acts on whitespace, so it follows your requirements and we can write, using a LC

```
[l.split() for l in open('data.txt').readlines()]
```

obtaining the following LOL

```
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']],
```

as you can see we are close to our target, but the elements of the inner lists are not numbers, but textual repersentations of numbers, i.e., strings.

We have to introduce a further step, that is converting strings to numbers. We have two choices, the builtins `int` and `float`, in your case it seems that you want integers so we want `int`, a function that accepts a single argument (that's not *exactly* true) either a number or a string.

If we pass to `int` the outcome of `l.split()` an error will be raised, because `l.split()` doesn't return a string but a list of strings... we have to 1. unpack the elements of the lists and 2. pack back the results into a list, in other words it is again a LC!

```
[int(s) for s in l.split()] # -> [1, 2, 3] for the first line, etc
```

Let's put the pieces together and you have your answer:

```
lol = [[int(s) for s in l.split()] for l in open('data.txt').readlines()]
```

It's really easy (if you already knew all the stuff I tried to explain, that is...)

Answer (score 2):

You could use csv module.

```
import csv
with open('file') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ")
    print([i for i in reader])
```

Output:

```
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy:

```
with open("/tmp/f") as f:
    m = [row.split() for row in f.read().split("\n") if row]

print(m)
```

Output:

```
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("data.txt") as inf:
    # skip header row
    next(inf, "")
    # parse data
    result = [[float(f) for f in line.split()] for line in inf]
```

results in

```
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
 [4.0, 5.0, 6.0],
 [7.0, 8.0, 9.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add type casting.

```
>>> file_path = '/home/Desktop/123.csv' 
>>> import csv
>>> with open(file_path) as fp:
...   reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=" ")
...   tmp = [i for i in reader]
...   result = []
...   for i in tmp:
...     result.append([int(j) for j in i])
... 
>>> print result
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file_list = []
f = open(file.txt, 'r')
for line in f.xreadlines():
    file_list.append([line])
f.close()
```

Comment: You really don't like explaining your answers, do you? Someone keeps flagging them.